# Kafka Topic ordering with Spring Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm trying to set up a system that will read from two different Kafka Topics - one for live messages and one for bulk messages. The hope is that, no matter how many messages are on the "bulk" topic, anything on the "live" topic is given preference.

It *seems* that Spring Kafka does this out of the box - sometimes.

What I've got is simply:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"sync-live", "sync-bulk"}, concurrency = "1")
```

And my Configuration is:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroup);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory
        = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

And sometimes this will do exactly what I want, and other times it won't. In fact, on a couple of occasions I've seen it switch from the "live" topic to the "bulk" one when there are still live messages to be processed!

Is there a way to tell Spring Kafka to only read from the second Topic when the first one is empty?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Spring, the distribution of messages from topics the consumer is subscribed to is a function of the broker.

The problem is you are using a single consumer (listener container) for both topics.

To get a dedicated consumer for each, use multiple annotations...

```
@KafkaListener(groupId = "live.group", topics = "sync-live", concurrency = "1")
@KafkaListener(groupId = "bulk.group", topics = "sync-bulk", concurrency = "1")
public synchronized void listen(...) { ... }
```

The `synchronized` will prevent both containers calling the listener at the same time. Omit it if that's not a problem.